# Supremum / Infimum

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is bounded and let $a< b$. Is is then true that
$$
\sup_{x \in (a,b)} f(x) - \inf_{y \in (a,b)} f(y) = \sup_{x,y \in (a,b)} | f(x)-f(y)| 
$$ ?

Comment: Yes this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Let $\def\eps{\varepsilon}$$\eps > 0$, then we can find $x, y \in (a,b)$, such that 
$\sup f < f(x) + \eps$, $\inf f > f(y) - \eps$ we have 
$$ \sup f - \inf f < f(x) - f(y) + 2\eps \le \sup |f(x) - f(y)| + 2\eps $$
On the other hand, given again $\eps > 0$, we can find $x,y \in (a,b)$ with 
$\sup |f(x) - f(y)| < |f(x) - f(y)| + \eps$. Assume wlog that $f(x) \ge f(y)$. Then 
$$ \sup |f(x) - f(y)| < |f(x) - f(y)| + \eps \le \sup f - \inf f + \eps. $$